# Window manager decorations disappear after mounting old home folder

Tags: nvidia, compiz, window-manager

I had a 15.04 system where the window manager decorations disappeared after I installed Nvidia drivers. I removed and purged them, but the decorations never came back.

So I reinstalled to 14.04, hoping this would fix things. With 14.04 and Nouveau, things worked fine, but when I mounted my `/home` disk from the old system, the window decorations disappeared again. I tried renaming `.cache/compizconfig-1/`, and then `.cache/` but neither did anything. Where is the offending file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiz in Ubuntu uses by default the dconf setting backend. The user data are stored in `~/.config/dconf/user`

```
$ file  ~/.config/dconf/user 
/home/username/.config/dconf/user: GVariant Database file, version 0
```

Better to copy that file from the new system home if you want to keep same user settings. If not or it doesn't work, remove it.